# Automate how the author appears in the text

Tags: macros, bibliographies, citing

I have a problem with LaTex and the style guide of the ISMAR papers.

They state that:

> when citing references, do not use the reference as a sentence
> object; e. g., wrong: “In [4] the authors describe . . . ”, correct:
> “Lorensen and Cline [4] describe . . . ”

Unfortunately, it seems that this process is not automated by them.

I have tried to write a command so that when someone writes e.g. `\citeISMAR{authorYEAR}` it will directly be converted to: *"Author et al. [1] conclude that [...]"* instead of `\cite{authorYEAR}` which turns it into *"[1] conclude that [...]"*. But my understanding of LaTex is not sufficient to at least evaluate whether something like that is even possible.

I tried it with
`\newcommand{citeISMAR}[1]{\citeauthor{#1} \cite{#1}}`
which seems to be completely wrong. I would first need a command to get the name of the author of a citation to include it. Something like
`\newcommand{citeAuthorName}[1]{\cite{#1}.author}`.

It seems that their template uses:
`\usepackage{cite}`
and the bibliographic style:
`\bibliographystyle{abbrv-doi-hyperref-narrow}`

I have researched that the `natbib` package can be used to achieve such things, but I am not sure I want to include it, as it might change things without me noticing.

Since there is someone on the team who is not really familiar with LaTex it would be nice to automate this process and just provide one command like \cite{}.

I would appreciate any help and suggestions on where to start my research to achieve this.

Comment: As always on this site, please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. A lot of people will pass on a question that is phrased like this.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I will try to create one and upload it as soon as I am home.

Comment: With `natbib` you would just use `\citet`. With `\usepackage{cite}` there is no such command. Plus your style would have to support this anyway. If the style you have to use does not support `natbib`'s authordate citations, LaTeX simply cannot obtain the author name in citations. You would have to use something like `usebib` to get the name, but usebib does not do name parsing and this is unlikely to go down well with the publisher.

Comment: Please, read the [the Overleaf tutorial](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Natbib_citation_styles). Although I can't reproduce your `.tex`, I believe this should work \setcitestyle{authoryear,open={((},close={))}} Put this line in the preambule (means before `\begin{document}`) and tune the parameters as you like. The explanation is in that tutorial. Good luck!

Comment: I suspect the intention is for you to hardcode the author component of such an inline citation. Without seeing at least the class and the bst, this isn't really answerable either way.

Answer (score -1):

If you use `biblatex` you can use the command `\citeauthor{}` to get the author. I created the command `\newcommand{\AuthorCite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1} \cite{#1}}` which seems to work fine. Here is the output:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\newcommand{\AuthorCite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1} \cite{#1}}

\begin{document}
\AuthorCite{einstein} concludes that [...]

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And the `sample.bib` file:

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}
```

Comment: The standard way to do this in `biblatex` would be `\textcite`. No need to define a new command. I generally do not recommend lobbing several `\...cite` commands together into a single `\newcommand`. Commands thus defined have issues with multiple citations (try `\AuthorCite{sigfridsson,worman}` from `biblatex-examples.bib` to see what I mean) and cannot easily deal with pre- and postnotes. Additionally, citation tracking might get thrown off because you have several `\...cite` commands at once. Use `\DeclareCiteCommand` if you need to define a new cite command.